# Disable cache in devtools is enabled by default every time I reopen chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I want "Disable cache" to be unchecked by default or at least remember my last option.
Right now it is always enabled when reopening chrome devtools.[image]

Comment: It's already remembered. What you describe is either a bug which I can't reproduce or maybe you change this option in another tab?

Comment: Aha so it did remember the option before. Not sure why its not working for me.
I open the devtool and disable the option.
Close devtools and open it again.
It's enabled..

Comment: Try clicking "Restore defaults" in devtools settings.

Comment: Clicking Restore defaults worked  

Answer (score 0):

wOxxOm comment solved it.

Clicking "Restore defaults" in devtools settings solved it.